# Is there a suitable pattern to combine key bindings?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, architecture, unreal-engine4, game-development

Making a RTS logic on UE4. I can bind class methods or lambdas to "OnPressed", "OnReleased", and "Axis" signals. Thinking about using the Guarded State Machine pattern with the Command pattern to define key conjunctions, but there is no trivial way to determine a final command at the last step. Need something like morphs.
For e.g.:

```
LeftClick = Nothing
LeftClick + Unit under cursor = Select unit
Shift + LeftClick = Nothing
Shift + LeftClick + Unit under cursor = Add unit to selection
Shift + LeftClick + Moving cursor + Units under cursor = Add units to selection
Ctrl + LeftClick + Unit under cursor = Remove unit from selection
RightClick = Nothing
RightClick + Units selected = Move units
```

Perhaps I should use the Behavior Tree pattern instead of the State Machine pattern? But the tree will be so big (the example just has been simplified).

Comment: Hey there, it may be worth further clarifying what "there is no trivial way to determine a final command at the last step. Need something like morphs." At the moment this *seems* like a input combination question, but the usage of an uncommon term like "morphs" and "final command" makes that uncertain

Answer (score 0):

Heyo, good first question! Apologies for the sloppy answer but a few key points:

1. For inputs to be used in conjunction, you'll need to manually handle the state yourself. For example, if you wanted Ctrl then LeftClick to do something different from LeftClick, then you'll need to remember that Ctrl was clicked earlier and do different behavior. In practice, this tends to be...

   - In Ctrl OnPressed, set a bool to true (and OnReleased set it to false)
   - In LeftClick OnPressed, check if that bool is true. If it is, do X behavior. Otherwise do Y behavior
2. Note that this is independent of your design pattern of choice. ie, regardless of whether you use a behavior tree or a state machine, you'll need to remember what happened with prior keys in order to do behavior in conjunction
3. On a final point - and apologies if I misunderstood the question - but you seem to be overcomplicating determining input combinations vs corresponding behavior with a given set of inputs. ie, LeftClick + "Unit under cursor" (assuming "Unit under cursor" isn't already stored state) isn't a separate input from LeftClick but rather what you check *after* the LeftClick OnPressed event occurs

   - No matter what design pattern you choose, you'll need to handle this on a case by case basis as coding/implementation normally goes. ie, "Did my raycast hit a unit or not?" -> { choose behavior }  will occur either way. I'm assuming this is what you're referring to as "morphs" and "final command"

Comment: And as a side note, I much prefer ECS with its inherent data-oriented approach which also makes it easy to decouple interlinking logic pretty easily. It's easy to add variations of existing design patterns like state machines on top of it in a well-maintainable way as well =)

Comment: Very good tips! Agree, there's no silver bullet as the simple decision